# Question in Munkres Analysis on manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to solve this problem, but I am having such a hard time trying to solve it. I am Ok with part $(a)$, but parts b and c I dont understand :s

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part (a) it is really easy to show the "if" part from Riemann condition.

In part (b) there is condition that among all sub-rectangles determined by $P$, those whose sides contain the newly added point have a combined volume no greater than $2M(\operatorname{mesh}P)(\operatorname{width}Q)^{n-1}$. So, you can easily prove that
$$0\leqslant L(f,P'')-L(f,P)\leqslant 2M(\operatorname{mesh}P)(\operatorname{width}Q)^{n-1}$$

In part (c) by part (b) you can get
$$0\leqslant L(f,P'')-L(f,P)\leqslant N\cdot 2M(\operatorname{mesh}P)(\operatorname{width}Q)^{n-1}\leqslant 2MN(\operatorname{width}Q)^{n-1}\frac{\epsilon}{8MN(\operatorname{width}Q)^{n-1}}=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$$
By this, you can easily show "else if" part.

Comment: how to proof the condition that you used in part (b) ? Since it seems not very obviously